# Asleep is to awake; as sleep is to _____?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

Is there no word that fills this precise role? I can say someone gets 10 hours of sleep. But can I say someone gets 10 hours of wake? That doesn't sound right to me but maybe it is. Does anyone know if 'wake' is wrong in this context as I believe it to be, or if there is a right word to fill in this blank at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although normally used to describe being awake when one should normally be asleep, the word *wakefulness* (the noun form of *wakeful*, defined below) can work here.

> **Wakeful** *adjective*
>   1.1 (Of a period of time) passed with little or no sleep
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wakeful?q=wakefulness#wakeful__9)

You can say that someone got 10 hours of wakefulness. Here's one instance from a web search (emphasis mine):

> The results showed that around **18 hours of wakefulness** produced performance
>   impairments in this test which were equivalent to the effects found at 0.05% BAC.
>   [- p.4, Williamson et al, Development of Measures of Fatigue: Using an Alcohol Comparison to Validate the Effects of Fatigue on Performance](https://infrastructure.gov.au/roads/safety/publications/2000/pdf/fatig_alc.pdf)